# UpdatePanel not refreshing on my radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have some radio buttons like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <p>YOUR AGE IS AN IMPORTANT FACTOR IN YOUR ABILITY TO TAKE ON INVESTMENT RISK. YOUR AGE IS:</p>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioBtnFirst" CssClass="radioBtnAge" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
     TextAlign="Right" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="radioBtnFirst_SelectedIndexChanged">
         <asp:ListItem Value="1">60 and over</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="2">50 - 59</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="3">40 - 49</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="4">30 - 39</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5">Under 30</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
</li>
```

Now somewhere donw I have a textbox where I want to get the value of the selected radiobutton. This is the code that is doing that:

```
protected void radioBtnFirst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    totalScore.Text = radioBtnFirst.SelectedValue;
}
```

I wanted to add UpdatePanel so it won't refresh the whole page but it's not working, when I press first one of the radio buttons it doesn't happen anything, but when I press the second time, it refreshes again the whole page.
This is the code that I used for UpdatePanel:

```
<h3>Total Score:</h3>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upScore" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="totalScore" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="radioBtnFirst" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: If you don't want the whole page to be refreshed when clicking the radiobuttons, you should put `radioBtnFirst` in an UpdatePanel also, possiblty with `UpdateMode="Always"`. Except for that, I tried something similar to your code and the textbox is updated even on the first click on a radio button.

Comment: Why involve an UpdatePanel at all? Why not do it with JavaScript? It requires no server interaction.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thank you, you were helpful, BTW the problem was in Page_Load method behind the code, and I fixed it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's ok, it's working. I figured out that the problem was behind the code in Page_Load method.